# How to get a result from repeating an experiment

Tags: statistics

I'm taking a first course in statistics now so this <s>might be</s> is a simple question.

Imagine an experiment:
The whole class (let's say 30 students) gets a small 20cm ruler and has to measure the length of a classroom. Because noone is perfect, you'll have 30 slightly different numbers. Now what is **the proper way** to conclude a result from these data?

A simple arithmetic mean first came to my mind but it won't give the right result...
Either an answer or any link for further reading is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a perfect result.  If all the students have a similar error of measurement, taking the mean is very reasonable.  If you believe they make an independent error each time they use the ruler, you can prove it is the right thing to do.  Maybe, though, one of the students makes a systematic error.  For example, the ruler he got might be $19.5$ cm long instead of $20.0$  His value will be far off the rest, so you might want to throw it out and average the rest.  Unfortunately, it could be that only one student got an accurate ruler and you are throwing out the good one and averaging the rest.  Too bad....